# Cubic Spline function in scipy.interpolate returns a numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I need to use `CubicSpline` to interpolated between points.  This is my function

```
cs = CubicSpline(aTime, aControl)
u = cs(t)   # u is a ndarray of one element.
```

I cannot convert `u` to a float.   `uu = float(u)` or `uu = float(u[0])` doesn't work in the function.
I can convert `u` to a float in the shell by `float(u)`.  This shouldn't work because I have not provided an index but I get an error if I use `u[0]`.
I have read something about `np.squeeze`.  I tried it but it didn't help.

I added a `print ("u=",u)` statement after the `u=cs(t)`.  The result was

```
u= [  1.88006889e+09   5.39398193e-01   5.39398193e-01]
```

How can this be?  I expect 1 value.  The second and third numbers look about right.

Comment: What is aTime, aControl, and t? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Comment: Main question: Have you checked the data type of t? If it is a numpy array, the output would be a numpy array as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  Programming error, of course but the error messages I got were very misleading.  I was calling the interpolate function with 3 values so it returned three vales.  Why I couldn't get just the one afterwards is still a mystery but now that I call the interpolate with just one value I get one float as expected.  Overall this still didn't help as the interpolate1d function is too slow.  I wrote my own cubic interpolate function that is MUCH faster.

Again, programming error and poor error messages were the problem.